# #gsheet export timesheet sheet in anual calendar view sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like some help for pulling people time activity in a global annual sheet

## The Purpose

Every week we report our time base on the activity and day of the week

## The Goal

Because we do this each week, I would like to export the data in an annual sheet before rewrite the data for the next week of activity.

## The source SheetName= 'Timesheet'

[image]

## The Data exported

1. In "A" The DATE of the time consumed from source (C:I)
2. In "B" The ACTIVITY from source (A:A)
3. In "C" The name of the people from source (B:B)
4. In "D" The time consumed by the person for the activity on the specific day of year from source (C:I)

## The destination SheetName= 'Anual_Timesheet'

[image]

## Conclusion

Every week by the script I will be able to keep the data automatically exported and save time without doing manual error.

## The File

The file for the purpose https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WzVbd8esjmJZJ0PnbUfnW8sS2KOTv6JikVD8vhtpqPg/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for your reading and help

Comment: It's not fully clear what the expected result is. Can you share a sanitized copy of the sheet in addition to the expected result?

Comment: I have rewrite the post and provide access to the file, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example script to archive the time records.  I made a sample data set for testing as shown.  The sheet names need to be changed to reflect your situation.

[image]

Code.gs

```
function saveTimeRecords() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let records = sheet.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow()-3,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    let dates = records.shift();  // get the dates and remove from records
    dates = dates.slice(2,8); // get only the columns with dates
    records.shift(); // remove headers
    let archive = [];
    records.forEach( record => {
      for( let i=2; i<9; i++ ) {
        if( record[i] !== "" ) {
          archive.push([dates[i-2],record[0],record[1],record[i]]);
        }
      }
    });
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,archive.length,archive[0].length).setValues(archive);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.Log(err);
  }
}
```

References

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
- [Array Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)